# How to use update and delete query in wordpress

Tags: php, plugin-development, mysql

First i write manually update, delete, insert and select query and execute data with `mysql_query` function

Like this:

Select query

```
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
$postSql = "SELECT DISTINCT post_id
            FROM " . $prefix . "postmeta As meta
            Inner Join " . $prefix . "posts As post
            On post.ID = meta.post_id
            Where post_type = 'product' 
            And post_status = 'publish'
            And meta_key Like '%product_img%'";
$postQry = mysql_query($postSql);
while ($postRow = mysql_fetch_array($postQry)) {
     $post_id = $postRow['post_id'];
}
```

Insert Query

```
$insert_images = "Insert Into " . $prefix . "postmeta(post_id,meta_key,meta_value) Value('$post_id','$meta_key','$data_serialize')";
        mysql_query($insert_images);
```

Update Query:

```
$update_price = "Update " . $prefix . "postmeta
                         Set meta_key = 'wpc_product_price'
                         Where post_id = $supportMetaID
                         And meta_key Like '%product_price%'";
 mysql_query($update_price);
```

Delete Query

```
mysql_query("Delete From " . $prefix . "postmeta Where meta_key IN ('product_img1','product_img2','product_img3')");
```

All queries are working perfectly ... but now i want to embed all queries in wordpress queries.

I can also use wordpress queries like

```
$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" );
$wpdb->insert( 
    'table', 
    array( 
        'column1' => 'value1', 
        'column2' => 123 
    ), 
);
$wpdb->update( 
    'table', 
    array( 
        'column1' => 'value1',  // string
        'column2' => 'value2'   // integer (number) 
    ), 
    array( 'ID' => 1 )
);
$wpdb->delete( 'table', array( 'ID' => 1 ) );
```

But you can see that i use `and / or` conditions in my queries. So any body help me how can i embed my queries in wordpress

Comment: WordPress offers [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) Class for doing all those. But a query like the first one can easily be achieved with [`WP_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) with less effort.

Answer (score 3):

## About UPDATE+INSERT:

I have made a function for myself, and might help you too, i.e. :

```
UPDATE_OR_INSERT('wp_users',  array('gender'=>'female'), array('name'=>'Monika') );
```

that will UPDATE A VALUE in column (where `name=monika`), but in case that value doesnt exists, then it creates a new record in DB.
Why this is necessary? because As far as i know, there is no sophisticated WP function, that will update data in DB (if value exists) or inserts data (if not exists). Instead, we use : `$wpdb->update()` or `$wpdb->insert()`. 
So, use that function, it helps:

```
function UPDATE_OR_INSERT($tablename, $NewArray, $WhereArray){          global $wpdb; $arrayNames= array_keys($WhereArray);
    //convert array to STRING
    $o=''; $i=1; foreach ($WhereArray as $key=>$value){ $o .= $key . ' = \''. $value .'\''; if ($i != count($WhereArray)) { $o .=' AND '; $i++;}  }
    //check if already exist
    $CheckIfExists = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ".$arrayNames[0]." FROM ".$tablename." WHERE ".$o);
    if (!empty($CheckIfExists))  { return $wpdb->update($tablename, $NewArray,  $WhereArray );}
    else                         { return $wpdb->insert($tablename,     array_merge($NewArray, $WhereArray) );  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Update Query:

```
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'tablename';

$wpdb->update( $table_name, array( 'role_id' => 1),array('user_id'=>$user_id));
```

Delete Query:

```
$wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'id' => $id ) );
```